# AccountManagerFuture not throwing OperationCanceled when pressing Back

Tags: android, accountmanager

I've implemented a custom AccountManager along the lines of [Github Gauges](https://github.com/github/gauges-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/gauges/authenticator/ApiKeyProvider.java#L55) or [Github Android Client](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/accounts/GitHubAccount.java)

More specifically, I'm implementing:

- AccountAuthenticatorService (like [here](https://github.com/github/gauges-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/gauges/authenticator/AccountAuthenticatorService.java))
- AccountAuthenticator (like [here](https://github.com/github/gauges-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/gauges/authenticator/GaugesAccountAuthenticator.java))
- ApiKeyProvider which calls `accountManagerFuture.getResult()`

When accountManagerFuture.getResult() is called, my LoginActivity is started like should be. However, when the back button is pressed, I'm not getting an OperationException as should be (on the GitHub Gauges project it seems like it's working)

Anyone has an idea how to start debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "when `accountManagerFuture.getResult()` is called"? Do you maintain a reference to the future after the back button is pressed and then call `getResult()` at some point afterwards? Because an `OperationCanceledException` will only be called if you explicitly call this method after the operation has been canceled.

Understanding the flow of events is a good place to start debugging the problem. When you press the back button `onBackPressed()` is called; `onBackPressed()` will then call `finish()`, and according to the source code for the [**`AccountAuthenticatorActivity`**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.java) class, the overriden `finish()` method will send the signal that eventually cancels the task. Does that help you get started?

Also note that when you press the back button the operation will only be cancelled if the operation is still running. If the operation has already completed then no exception will be thrown (since there isn't any currently active operation for the framework to cancel). In other words, **you might not get an exception when you press the back button**... it all depends on whether the operation has already completed or not.

If you are still having trouble I would consider adding some code to your original question because otherwise it will be difficult for us to help you out any further. :)

Comment: Many Many thanks. The key thing you mentioned is the finish() being overidden by AccountAuthenticatorActivity. At some point I changed my activity to inherit from PagerActivity and forgot to copy-paste the AccountAuthenticatorActivity methods!